# How to make Word Wrap insert newlines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, word-wrap

I know kate has a feature that automatically breaks a line with a newline if the line
exceeds beyond a certain number of characters like 80.

Notepad++ has a word wrap feature under the Views table, but it doesn't insert a newline
character. It simply splits long lines visually without inserting actual newlines.

Is there a plug-in or feature in Notepad++ to automatically break long lines using newlines automatically?

Answer (score 11):

To have Notepad++ insert a CR/LF based on the width of the window (equal to where it wraps if you have selected View | **Word Wrap**):

1. Select text
2. **CTRL+I**  (*or* Edit | Line Operations | **Split Lines**)

This is **nice** because it lets you **visually preview** where the breaks will occur by **resizing the window**. It does not split at a specific column number (unless your window is sized at that column).

- Use CTRL+J to Join lines (the inverse command)

If you want to wrap at a specific column number try the Plugins | TextFX Edit | ReWrap feature. N.B. If you don't want the newlines inserted at column 72, then you need to copy the column number into the clipboard first.  Unconventional, but it works.

If you used to use UltraEdit, this is similar to the "Convert wrap to line ends" feature.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I love you (moar text here)

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if there's a plugin, and I can't find any menu item to do this but it can be done with regular expression replace all...

- Find: `\s(?<=.{80})`
- Replace: `$0\r\n`

This will find the nearest space `\s` after 80 characters look behind `(?<=.{80})` and replace with the entire match `$0` followed by carriage return `\r` & new line `\n` for DOS/Windows.

Use just a new line `\n` for Linux.

Comment: Works perfectly - should be marked as correct answer..

Comment: almost perfect - word wrapping should allow me to limit the maximum line length, so I need the last space *before* 80.

Comment: Also, pay attention to the "Search Mode" box in the lower left corner of Notepad++'s Find/Replace screen. The default radio button is "Normal". Change this to "Regular Expression", and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This use lookbacks and lookaheads to...

1. find the first character after 80
2. find the consecutive non-space character set followed by (1)
3. match the space when followed by (2)

It works for me to replace the last space before character 80 with a newline.

Find: `\s(?=\S*((?<=.{80}).))`
Replace: `\n`

Note that the `Replace` button in N++ does not work when inserting a `\n`. I think this is a bug, but using `Replace All` works fine. Note also that replace all will search the next  80 character block after the match (space), which should be the correct behavior for breaking up really long lines.

Comment: Nice approach, it works pretty fine.

Answer (score 1):

Find the last space **before** the 80th character, and split the line at that position:

- Find `(.{1,80})(\h+\R?|\R)`
- Replace `\1\r\n`